# MySql MINUS (opposite of intersaction)

Tags: mysql, inventory

I have two tables

- inventory_lot_transactions and
- inventory_lot_serials

I am logging all the transactions IN and OUT of inventory by lot's. Every lot that gets booked in/out from warehouse has it's own batch of serial numbers that get logged for every IN and OUT transaction.

Now I would like to get all the serial numbers that are still available in X warehouse. Basically I would like to achieve this:

```
SELECT serials FROM table_a where transaction_type=In
MINUS
SELECT serials FROM table_a where transaction_type=Out
```

I have prepared two SQL fiddles:

1. This is the list A of serials that came into one warehouse http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3a4ab/7
2. This is the list B of serials that went out of the warehouse http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3a4ab/8

Basically I would like to select all the serials that are still available in this warehouse. E.g. List A - List B.

Comment: You have the same query two times but with different parameters for one column. Doesn't that mean if it is "not out" it is "in"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I understood correctly, you should be able to use NOT IN in your where-condition. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3a4ab/10

```
select IL.lot_id, ILS.serial_id 
from inventory_lot_serials ILS
left join inventory_lots IL ON IL.id=ILS.inventory_lot_id
where 
  IL.type='In' and 
  IL.warehouse_location_id=500
  AND ILS.serial_id NOT IN 
(SELECT ILS.serial_id 
    from inventory_lot_serials ILS
    left join inventory_lots IL ON IL.id=ILS.inventory_lot_id
    where 
      IL.type='Out' and 
  IL.warehouse_location_id=500)
```

Comment: Oh so easy :). I was thinking so much about it I forgot on `NOT IN` :)

Answer (score 1):

Possibly use LEFT OUTER JOINs to avoid the use of sub queries:-

```
SELECT IL.lot_id, 
        ILS.serial_id 
FROM inventory_lots IL 
INNER JOIN inventory_lot_serials ILS ON IL.id = ILS.inventory_lot_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN inventory_lots ILO ON ILO.lot_id = IL.lot_id AND ILO.type = 'Out' AND ILO.warehouse_location_id = 500 
LEFT OUTER JOIN inventory_lot_serials ILSO ON ILO.id = ILSO.inventory_lot_id AND ILS.serial_id  = ILSO.serial_id
WHERE IL.type = 'In' 
AND IL.warehouse_location_id = 500
AND ILSO.inventory_lot_id IS NULL
```

This does an inner join to the inventory in table (as you are only interested in records where there is inventory coming in there is no need for an outer join on this), then a LEFT OUTER JOIN to the inventory out table. Then the WHERE clause discards items that are found on the inventory out table.

SQL fiddle for it here:-

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/10c0a/8

Comment: @PrimozRome - done some minor mods. Gives the same results. Without sub queries I would expect this to be quicker, especially with large amounts of data

Comment: Now it works correct, thanks a lot. I will test which one is faster and accordingly set as accepted answer.